# OpenSteer on Xbox 360?

Tags: c++, xna, xbox360

I want to use [OpenSteer](http://opensteer.sourceforge.net/) for my game that I want to be compatible with the Xbox 360. I have heard that since it is a wrapper for a C++ library, it will work in XNA on a PC, but not on the Xbox. Is there no way to make it compatible?

**UPDATE:** The C++ version may not be, but what about [OpenSteerDotNet](http://code.google.com/p/opensteerdotnet/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the OpenSteerDotNet homepage:

> It should work fine with XNA Game
>   Studio Express, including the XBox 360
>   runtime.

Answer (score 1):

No, not if you're not a professional game developer, got an agreement with Microsoft and pay them for their SDK (hardware include).

XNA don't allow **native code** on the XBox360.

You're only alternative is to use a .Net implementation of the same library, OpenSteerDotNet as suggested in comments.

Comment: @Rosarch in the OpenSteerDotNet project summary it says "It should work fine with XNA Game Studio Express, including the XBox 360 runtime."

Comment: Ok then the question changed, i'll add that to the answer.